# Fully securing web page for public use

Tags: php, security, authentication

I'm starting to work on my biggest project yet and if it's succesful it's going to be used by thousands of users. Unfortunately my experience in PHP has been limited to smaller projects only used in limited and closed groups of people or private usage so security never was my biggest concern. I want to create the most secure system possible but I can't find any good reference.

What should I know about securing a login system or storing sensitive data input by users? Is there any book you can recommend or a comprehensive guide? Or should I buy/use a premade system? I realize perfecting it is going to take a lot of time and I'm willing to invest it for it to be as secure as possible. I've already read up a lot about security and what to look for but I want to be sure I didn't miss anything. Also I couldn't find any confirmed secure code example apart from [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL). Is this all I need to know?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any book you can recommended or a comprehensive guide?

[Owasp.org](http://www.owasp.org/) Is a good starting point.

> Or should I buy/use some premade system?

Using a pre-made system like WordPress or a framework is a good starting point to achieve a good security (because you use the code that a "more expert coder" write for you).

> Is all that I need to know?

Nope. There are a lot of things that come with experience. Also there are a lot of things that are normally out of scope for a coder.